# how can I avoid the "can't read superblock" error when mounting a FAT32 FS?

Tags: linux

After associating a disk image with the dev/loop0 device I can't mount the file system in /dev/loop0p1

```
root@reading2 Documents]# fdisk -l /dev/loop0

Disk /dev/loop0: 31.9 GB, 31914983424 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3880 cylinders, total 62333952 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/loop0p1   *        8192    62333951    31162880    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
[root@reading2 Documents]# ls -l /mnt
total 0
[root@reading2 Documents]# mount -t vfat /dev/loop1 /mnt
mount: block device /dev/loop1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/loop1: can't read superblock
[root@reading2 Documents]#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in your `mount` command.

You mounted a disk image to a loopback device at `/dev/loop0`, and its partition then became `/dev/loop0p1`.

Therefore, to mount it, you would use something like:

```
mount -o ro -t vfat /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

However, you typed in `/dev/loop1` in the `mount` command instead.

Comment: This is a disk image that was presented to the system with the following command:

    losetup /dev/loop0 cam.img

Trying your suggestion I get the following:

   [root@reading2 Documents]# mount -o ro -t vfat /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
   mount: special device /dev/loop0p1 does not exist
   [root@reading2 Documents]#